# VIM: autocomplete plugin to work with gtags

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, gnu-global

I have just moved from ctags to gtags for my huge C Project. But I couldnt find any vim autocomplete plugin that works with gtags. gtags is so widely used and much more efficient than ctags. I am sure I am missing something here. Someone must have integrated gtags with any autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to write my own plugin for this. Here is the link if someone needs it.
https://github.com/kanwar-saad/gtagsomnicomplete

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple `'omnifunc'` for Vim, that uses GNU `global` for completion:

```
augroup GlobalComplete
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType c setlocal omnifunc=GlobalComplete
augroup END

function! GlobalComplete(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart == 1
    return s:LocateCurrentWordStart()
  else
    return split(system('global -c ' . a:base), '\n')
  endif
endfunction

function! s:LocateCurrentWordStart()
  let l:line = getline('.')
  let l:start = col('.') - 1
  while l:start > 0 && l:line[l:start - 1] =~# '\a'
    let l:start -= 1
  endwhile
  return l:start
endfunction
```

See also:

- [The original code on GitHub](https://github.com/astyagun/dotvim/blob/e0442d56873312b53d9914776d028f82d97d2fe8/my_plugin/global_complete.vim)
- [More information on Vim Omni completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion)